# The role of か in [VERB+か+のNOUN]

Tags: grammar, particles, nominalization

The following is from one of the definitions of a word in goo辞書:

> [どちらに傾くかの度合い](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/189420/meaning/m0u/%E5%88%86/)

I do not understand why **か** is used here instead of こと.

Usually, I would expect to see **の** (or こと) nominalize a verb. Nonetheless, I reckon it would be ungrammatical here, since what follows is the possessive **の**, and a noun (**度合い**).

Alternatively, if I were to write this phrase myself, I would simply attach the plain verb (**傾く**) to the noun (**度合い**):

> どちらに傾く度合い

Which seems to express the same thing to me.

I do not think this **かの** is **かのように**, but what about **彼の**? If I understand correctly, **彼の** is simply an old-fashioned way of saying **あの**. If so, the phrase could be rewritten thus:

> どちらに傾くあの度合い

Which seems strange to me. (I am a low-level beginner though.) Could someone please help me understand the grammar at work here?

ご教授どうぞよろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: This may be helpful background: http://www.imabi.net/kaiiiindirectquestion.htm

Comment: I can understand all the sentences listed in the link, and I think I've seen all the grammar covered there. Oddly, tho, I still can't parse this phrase correctly. I'd thought about the possibility of this か functioning as a embedded question marker before I posted this question, but I just don't see the necessity of it. Maybe I don't really get all these grammar points after all. Explanatory/nominalizing ん/の/こと is really hard for me.

Comment: One thing I have to say about Imabi is that it is overly technical for someone like me. I can function fairly well in English, yet I have very little knowledge in terms of grammar. Therefore, his approach unfortunately really doesn't suit my learning style. Thanks for sharing though.

Comment: @YetiApe Seeing that you are a Mandarin Chinese speaker, I can see why you don't think the か is necessary. In Chinese, there isn't a "special" grammar for indirect questions. You just kind of put the question as it is into the sentence and it all works out. But in Japanese, the か is necessary. English kind of has something like this as well. Compare "I know _what that is_" and "I know _what is that_". The latter is ungrammatical. In English the subject-verb order is preserved in indirect questions, while in direct questions it is not.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. By not necessary though, I was talking about the necessity of using an embedded question at all, rather than why か was needed in an embedded question. Two replies I got on HiNative cleared things up for me though. I'll try to make an answer myself later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two native speakers on HiNative confirmed for me that it was indeed an embedded question:

> どちらに傾くか。 Which side (out of two) does it lean towards?

What caused me to have a hard time getting it was in fact my mere oversight of a telltale sign, "**どちら**." It had been begging for my attention the whole time.

While I am uncertain and have nothing to quote from, I will just go ahead and assert that `when a *subordinate clause begins with a question word, e.g. どこ, だれ,` **か** `is always needed to mark it as an embedded question.` Should this assertion prove to be wrong, hopefully someone would come along, slap me in the face, and warn everyone else of my blatant blasphemy.
* *Not sure if subordinate clause is the right term. Ain't been a fan of grammar.*

By this assumption, I would also assume that the following is wrong as well:

> どちらに傾く度合い

Finally, the original phrase in the question:

> どちらに傾くかの度合い the degree of which side (out of two) it leans towards

This か makes perfect sense now. Phew.

Comment: "when a subordinate clause _begins_ with a question word" <--- not just "begins". If the subordinate clause _is a question_. e.g. Yes/no questions: **もう始まっているかどうか**はわからない

Comment: Again thank you for helping a lost fella out. I meant to stress how a question word in a subordinate clause necessitates the clause being an embedded question. In other words, removing か is not grammatical. Does this make sense? Hm... I might have to figure out a better wording sometime.